# Spring RestTemplate not releasing connection for null responses

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, java-8, resttemplate

I have a spring-boot application making a bunch of REST backend calls.
One of the Rest backend is throwing a ConnectionPoolTimeoutException.
After further investigation, I suspect that the connections are not closed for that backend when the response is an error or is null.

Tried debugging Spring RestTemplate code and saw a line:

```
finally {
            if (response != null) {
                response.close();
            }
        }
```

which looks like does not close connections if response was null.
Has anyone faced similar issue and what was the solution.
I am thinking of writing an interceptor which will always close the connection

Comment: I have already read these similar posts
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39795236/does-resttemplate-automatically-release-connection

Comment: Any updates on this?!

Comment: Found something similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31597696/resttemplate-connectionpooltimeoutexception-timeout-waiting-for-connection-fr/63438805#63438805

But does not say how they closed the connection

Comment: How do you plan on closing the connection since the close method is on the response object which is null?  If response == null then response.close() is guaranteed to throw a NPE.